# Is it bad to put your imgur client id in javascript?

Tags: javascript, api-key, imgur, clientid

I'm working on an application that uses imgur as hosting service and I'll be uploading images to imgur using javascript. But that means I have to put the client id in my code so everyone will be able to see my client id when they look at the source. Is this bad and if so what can I do as a workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only bad if you don't want other people use your client id.

You can use node.js to use the same javascript you are using now, but on the server side.

That way you don't have to learn a new language, but get all the benefits from keeping it on the server.

Good luck,

bovako

Comment: Thanks! I don't want to create too much server side cpu load. But I don't think there's another way :/ then again people would still be able to send their images to my server which sends it to imgur. So they would still be using my client id... isn't there a way to refresh my client id every once in a while?

Comment: Not easily no :( and you'd just keep the same problem.